# How to post to a Facebook feed with no image using the graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how to make facebook NOT set a default image if you dont specify the 'picture' argument?

I have tried:
blank = image auto set from website link
0 = all out fail with no message
null = fail with error message
removing 'picture' altogether from the array = image auto set from website link

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well, and found this rather useless SO post.  Then I figured it out, and thought I'd answer it now that it's almost a month old.

I got around it (as suggested in a comment on [this post](http://sudocode.net/article/318/update-facebook-news-feed-using-the-graph-api-in-php/)) by specifying a non-existent URL for the image.  I just used `http://www.noimage.faketld` for mine, since that's pretty assuredly never going to resolve to anything.  It now produces a nice gray line (as if it was being quoted), which I don't think can be removed, but looks decent enough imo.

Comment: This works, but that fake url still go with the link when you post and your friend can still click it. I think this doesn't provide the best ui experience.

Comment: this doesnt work, instead of the image a blank square is shown

Comment: Not surprising, as this post is from almost 4 years ago, and Facebook's API has gone through countless iterations since then.  I don't have any better suggestions.